# CSS rules for :visited won't work (beside color)?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

So I wanted to make a checkmark on each link somebody visited. This is basic CSS but somehow `:visited` will only accept `color` and no other rules. I've tested it on newest Chrome and FF on Mac and also on MS Edge 14 - same behavior.

Here is also a [codepen](http://codepen.io/gab/pen/ObLaNW) for testing

---

```
<a href="https://gab3.de">gab3.de</a>
<br>
<a href="https://gabrielw.de">gabrielw.de</a>
```

---

```
a:visited {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

a:visited:before {
  content: "\2713 ";
}
```

---

So what's the problem?

[image: demo]

Comment: You cant't do that. https://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy#limits

Comment: There is privacy issues vith `:visited`, that's why it's limited compared to `:hover` and `:active`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Sorry for the duplicate, haven't found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the properties that can be changed with :visited:

1. **color**
2. **List item**
3. **background-color**
4. **border-color (and its sub-properties)**
5. **outline-color**

The color parts of the fill and stroke properties
You can only use :visited to change those properties.

This are due to privacity concerns, as css tricks states on this information: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/